# Replace all real numeric and avoid missing values

Tags: r

I have a list of objects that want to replace them with 'char' if they are missing value or character, and replace with 'Number' if they are real number for example

```
NA >>> 'chr'
'NA' >>> 'chr'
5 >>> 'num'
'5' >>> 'num'
'test' >>> 'chr'
```

I tried this but it

```
x %>% {if(is.na(.)) 'char' else if(is.numeric(as.numeric(.))) 'number' else 'char'}]
```

but the problem is that this is.numeric(as.numeric('NA')) returns TRUE .

Comment: `NA` is a missing value, so a missing value in numeric data is numeric. The `NA` value in R can be coerced to various data types.

Comment: @BenNorris how can I change my code to replace it with 'char' if it NA

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use the built-in `type.convert` to make this more reliable:

```
L <- list(1, NA, "NA", "text", "5")

lapply(L, \(x) {
  tc <- type.convert(x, as.is=TRUE)
  out <- rep("char", length(x))
  out[is.na(tc)] <- "char"
  out[is.numeric(tc)] <- "number"
  out
})
#[[1]]
#[1] "number"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "char"
#
#[[3]]
#[1] "char"
#
#[[4]]
#[1] "char"
#
#[[5]]
#[1] "number"
```